# If I add devices within the router settings to a LAN, will those devices be able to ping each other?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan

I'm just wondering if I add two devices where it says "add" if they would be able to ping each other then.

[Page where I'm thinking of adding devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOZ6o.jpg)

Comment: Hi Colin! :)  Thanks for using SU.  The page you are showing has nothing to do with what you are asking with the exception of the fact that if you use this page to reserve IPs for specific devices, then these devices will know each other's IP addresses FOR SURE.  Generally, if your devices know each others addresses (by lookup, hardcoding, or whatever), then responding to a ping is up to the settings of the individual operating system and not the router itself.

Comment: @John gave a nice answer.. I didn't even talk about subnets in my comment.  Networking can be complicated and John did a nice job of getting to the point.

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas! I was wondering about that regarding that page haha. Thanks for the info about OS level settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a device using vanilla DHCP or else using DHCP Reservation (using device MAC address or other identifier) the devices will be able to see each other.

Make sure you are using just one subnet for ease and simplicity.

I do this here and do this frequently.  No issues.

Some devices may need Ping enabled but that does not impede connection and file sharing if the connection setup is set up properly.

Comment: Thanks! I assume most home routers use vanilla DHCP for IP allocation? I just tested and realized I can ping my printer, but not my iPhone, so I guess the ios has a firewall or something?